# Terminal does not use .bashrc variables, but recognized them

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, pop-os, cmake

I have installed the latest Pop!_OS version on my new computer and wanted to set the following environment variables:

```
CC=/usr/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja
```

Instead of typing `export CC=/usr/bin/clang` each time I open a new terminal, I added these variables to the end of my .bashrc in my home folder (~/.bashrc). When I now type the command `echo $CC`, the result I get is the expected result "/usr/bin/clang". Same goes for `echo $CXX` and `echo $CMAKE_GENERATOR`.

When I now run CMAKE however, I do not get a build.ninja file. Only when I type `export CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja` in my terminal does CMAKE generate a build.ninja file. I am confused by this behaviour.

I am not sure why `echo $CMAKE_GENERATOR` prints "Ninja" correctly, but does not use it and also why it works after I type `export CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja` in my terminal. By my understanding, the `export` command sets an environment variable for the current terminal session and adding an environment variable to the .bashrc sets it for all future terminal sessions.

What I have tried:

- I used `printenv`, which does not show the environment variables I set in the .bashrc, BUT, if I type `export CC=/usr/bin/clang` for example and then run `printenv` it does show up in the printed variables. ***I suspect this weird behavior to be an indication of what's wrong, but I do not know why this behavior happens***.
- When researching this, I have seen posts mentioning that there is a certain order in which the .bash_rc and .profile are being run, but since I have tried putting the variables in all of these files and it not working, this seems not to be the issue. I do not have a .bashrc_profile file, which has been mentioned in posts I have read and by my understanding I do not need one either.
- Ticking the "Run command as a login shell" box under Preferences -> Command of my terminal. This did not work. I have since unticked this option.
- I thought about editing either the /etc/profile or /etc/bash.bashrc file, but since those are read only and I am fairly new to linux, I would prefer not to meddle with such files.
- I have tried to find a fix by reading posts on the internet, but I feel like I have not been able to correctly phrase my question or been able to find a solution.

My .bashrc

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples


# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

CC=/usr/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja
```

My .profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: If you have just `CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja`, then the variable is set in the shell, but not exported to processes the shell launches. That's what the `export` command is for. So, you need `export CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja` in the startup file, same as if you entered the command manually. There's no magic in the `.bashrc` file, nothing that would make the plain assignment any different from one entered manually on the command line. It's just shell commands. In Bash, you can use `declare -p CMAKE_GENERATOR` to see the attributes of the variable, if it shows `-x`, it's exported, if it doesn't, it isn't.

Comment: @ilkkachu I have added export in front of my three lines in the .bashrc and this has fixed my problem. I misunderstood what export does. Thank you for your help!